# How Can ignore @ in Pattern in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want write pattern to my textbox in view
this textbox will hold email value
but i want write RegEx but i received error because RegEx contains @

i wrote @@ but still doesn't work

My Code

```
<input type="text" name="Emails" id="Emails" class="form-control Div-heigh" placeholder="To...." required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look to create a HTML Helper, like so;

```
 public static class ValidationExtensions
 {
      public static string EmailRegex(this HtmlHelper helper)
      {
           return @"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";
      }
 }
```

Then use it in your view;

```
<input requiredPattern="@Html.EmailRegex()" />
```

This will be re-useable between views and separate a complex regex (a programmer artefact) from html (more of a designer task).

**EDIT:** link to a longer [article about creating helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).